# Portable Library Tools Release Candidate

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, portable-class-library, portable-library-tools

Anybody know if Portable Library Tools Release Candidate is scheduled to go RTM, or is this the final version as released 5/2?

Referencing this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's gone RTM: http://www.uxmagic.com/blog/post/2011/06/16/Portable-Library-Tools-Now-RTM-VS2010-RTM-SP1.aspx